# Pass JSON with jquery ajax to a variable in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

This script doesn't work to pass data in a variable on PHP.

**script.js**

```
$(document).on('click', '.variant_model', function(){
    var model_id = this.id;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://www.mod-fusion.fr/console",
        //dataType: 'json',
        data: {"model_id":model_id},
        success: function(){
            $('#result').html(model_id); // work fine
        }
    });
});
```

**script.php**

```
echo '<li>
    <a href="#" id="'.$v['modelId'].'" class="variant_model">
        <span class="'.$v['brand_name'].'_text">'.$v['model_name'].'</span</a>
    </li>';

$return = $_POST;
if(isset($return)){
    $return["model_id"] = json_encode($return);
    echo json_encode($return); // doesn't work, it return {"model_id":"[]"}
}
echo'<div id="result"></div>'; // work fine
```

Thank's to find solution with me.

Comment: What doesnt work? What were you expecting? What have you tried to resolve it? What is the meaning of this question? The Life? The Universe?

Comment: @nadir What is "this.id" ? Did you check if its defined?

Comment: "this.id" is the value of the id in the "a variant_model".
I know "model_id" it's ok because the success works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You have a double json_encode and after send json you don't write nothing else, try this:

```
$return = $_POST; 
if(isset($return)) {    
    $return["model_id"] = $return;
    echo json_encode($return);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Than'ks for your help, but it's doesn't work. I still have {"model_id":[]}

Comment: What's the expected behavior of the PHP script

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(isset($_POST["model_id"])
{
   $json = json_decode($_POST["model_id"]);
   echo json_encode($json);
}
```

Make sure that the keys of the json values are between " ".

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that right away stand out to me.

```
$(document).on('click', '.variant_model', function(){
```

Should be

```
$('.variant_model').on('click', function(){
```

You don't want to track a click event on the document, and it's bad practice.
https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing

Check to see also that `var model_id = this.id;` returns a value. You can do this with `console.log(model_id);`.

You are not passing any value in your php code either. It should be:

```
$return = $_POST;
if(isset($return['model_id']))
{
   //$return["model_id"] = json_encode($return);
   echo json_encode($return['model_id']); // doesn't work, it return {"model_id":"[]"}
}
echo'<div id="result"></div>'; // work fine
```

Edit; Forgot to add this too:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://www.mod-fusion.fr/console",
        //dataType: 'json',
        data: {"model_id":model_id},
        success: function(data){
            $('#result').html(data); // work fine
        }
    });
```